# Make 2008 from Φ (Golden Ratio)

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

I know that [questions of the form "*Use [arbitrary set of numbers] to make 2018*" seem to be not very well recieved in the last days](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6186/yet-another-2018-puzzle). That's why this puzzle is about making **2008**.

But instead of using some randomly chosen numbers, you will use the most beautiful number I can imagine: [$\Phi = \tfrac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \sqrt{5} \right)$ – the Golden Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).

To make 2008 you may use

- the operators $+$, $-$, $\cdot$, $/$

  exponentiation

  brackets $($ $)$

and any number of instances of $\Phi$. The answer with the least number of $\Phi$s will be accepted.

You may not use operators or functions other than in this list, so don't even ask for rounding ($\lfloor$ $\rfloor$, $\lceil$ $\rceil$) or logarithm ($\log_a (x)$). If you want to use roots, this is ok as long as you express them as exponent: $\sqrt[n]{x} = x^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Comment: I see from your example $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ that you allow the number $1$.  I assume that $x$ and $n$ has to be created from Φ's?

Comment: @StigHemmer $\frac\Phi\Phi=1$ ;-) also no, I don't think $1$ is allowed, it just explains how roots should be represented.

Comment: And although $\Phi$ itself is an interesting number, none of the solutions posted use any of its properties besides $\Phi \neq 0$.

Comment: @ivan100sic When I created this puzzle I acutally thought of a way that would use the properties of $\Phi$, but unfortunately the simple solutions outperform it regarding the number of $\Phi$s used. But the [linked question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59619/make-439204-from-%ce%a6-golden-ratio) doesn't have this loophole.

Comment: **Fun fact:** $$2008=7^4-7^3-7^2-1.$$ That is pretty cool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Score:

> 21

The solution:

> $ \frac{x+x}{x} \cdot ( \frac{x+x+x+x}{x} + (\frac{x}{x} + (\frac{x+x+x}{x})^{ \frac{x+x}{x} })^ {\frac{x+x+x}{x}})$ where $x = \phi $.

Based on

> $ 2 \cdot (4 + (1 + 3^2)^3) $

Comment: Not that I could come up with anything better but it’s slightly disappointing that the golden ratio could really be replaced with “any positive number”. Not just for this answer but all/most answers

Answer (score 12):

Update...

> <s>25</s>   23

Using:

> $N = \frac{\phi + \phi + ...}{\phi}$
>  and simple substitution into:
>  $2008 = 2048 - 40 = 8 \cdot (256 - 5) = 2^3 \cdot (2^{(2^3)} - 5)$:
>
>  $\frac{\phi + \phi}{\phi} ^{\frac{\phi + \phi + \phi}{\phi}} \cdot (\frac{\phi + \phi}{\phi} ^{(\frac{\phi + \phi}{\phi} ^{\frac{\phi + \phi + \phi}{\phi}})} - \frac{\phi + \phi + \phi + \phi + \phi}{\phi})$

---

Previous attempt (less "golfed")...

> 38 $\phi$s...

Using:

> $1 = \frac{\phi}{\phi}$
>  and simple substitution into:
>  $2008 = 2000 + 8 = 2^4 \cdot 5^3 + 2^3$:
>
>  $(\frac{\phi}{\phi}+\frac{\phi}{\phi})^{(\frac{\phi}{\phi}+\frac{\phi}{\phi}+\frac{\phi}{\phi}+\frac{\phi}{\phi})} \cdot (\frac{\phi}{\phi}+\frac{\phi}{\phi}+\frac{\phi}{\phi}+\frac{\phi}{\phi}+\frac{\phi}{\phi})^{(\frac{\phi}{\phi}+\frac{\phi}{\phi}+\frac{\phi}{\phi})} + (\frac{\phi}{\phi}+\frac{\phi}{\phi})^{(\frac{\phi}{\phi}+\frac{\phi}{\phi}+\frac{\phi}{\phi})}$

Comment: Now I feel silly. Well done!

Comment: The one who should feel silly is **me**. I should have checked for simpler solutions than mine. Hopefully you still had fun. [Here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59619/make-439204-from-%CE%A6-golden-ratio) is a follow-up that is very unlikely to be solved _that_ easy.

Answer (score 7):

For everybody who wants to laugh at my unnecessarily complicated answer (**Beware!** This will spoiler the right answer to [this follow-up question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59619/make-439204-from-%ce%a6-golden-ratio).):

> $2008 = 2207 - 199$,
>  where $2207 = L(16)$ and $199 = L(11)$ – the $16$th and $11$th [Lucas number](https://oeis.org/A000204)s, respectively. The $n$th Lucas number can be expressed by $\Phi$ as
>  $$L(n) = \Phi^n + \left( - \Phi \right)^{-n}.$$
>  With this
>  $$\begin{align} 2008 &= \overbrace{\left( \Phi^{16} + \Phi^{-16} \right)}^{2207} - \overbrace{\left( \Phi^{11} - \Phi^{-11} \right)}^{199} = \Phi^{10} \left( \Phi^6 - \Phi \right) + \Phi^{-12} \left( \Phi + \frac{\Phi}{\Phi^5} \right) \\ &= \Phi^{\frac{\Phi + \Phi}{\Phi} \cdot \frac{\Phi + \Phi + \Phi + \Phi + \Phi}{\Phi}} \left( \Phi \Phi \Phi \Phi \Phi \Phi - \Phi \right) + \Phi^{- \frac{\Phi + \Phi + \Phi + \Phi}{\Phi} \cdot \frac{\Phi + \Phi + \Phi}{\Phi}} \left( \Phi + \frac{\Phi}{\Phi \Phi \Phi \Phi \Phi} \right). \end{align}$$
>  Unfortunately this takes 34 $\Phi$s – much more than the [accepted answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/59644/40914).

Answer (score 7):

Our first step is to construct some identities:

> $1 = \Phi * \Phi - \Phi$ which has 3 $\Phi$s

As my kindergarten daughter can tell me,

> $2 = 1 + 1 = \Phi * \Phi + \Phi * \Phi - \Phi - \Phi$ which has 6 $\Phi$s

Expanding further:

> $5 = 2 * 2 + 1 = (\Phi * \Phi + \Phi * \Phi - \Phi - \Phi) * (\Phi * \Phi + \Phi * \Phi - \Phi - \Phi) + \Phi * \Phi - \Phi$ which has 15 $\Phi$s.

And throw it into the soup:

> $2008 = ((5*5*5*2)+1)*2*2*2 = ((((\Phi * \Phi + \Phi * \Phi - \Phi - \Phi) * (\Phi * \Phi + \Phi * \Phi - \Phi - \Phi) + \Phi * \Phi - \Phi)*((\Phi * \Phi + \Phi * \Phi - \Phi - \Phi) * (\Phi * \Phi + \Phi * \Phi - \Phi - \Phi) + \Phi * \Phi - \Phi)*((\Phi * \Phi + \Phi * \Phi - \Phi - \Phi) * (\Phi * \Phi + \Phi * \Phi - \Phi - \Phi) + \Phi * \Phi - \Phi)*(\Phi * \Phi + \Phi * \Phi - \Phi - \Phi))+\Phi * \Phi - \Phi)*(\Phi * \Phi + \Phi * \Phi - \Phi - \Phi)*(\Phi * \Phi + \Phi * \Phi - \Phi - \Phi)*(\Phi * \Phi + \Phi * \Phi - \Phi - \Phi)$

For a total of

> 72 $\Phi$s

using only the properties of $\Phi$ - none of these operations would apply to any other real number.

For using way less $\Phi$ instances at the expense of accuracy, we can express the number 2008

> In base phi as 101 001 000 000 000

Which expands to

> $$ \frac{\Phi^{\Phi^{\Phi^{\Phi{^\Phi}}}}}{\Phi} + ({\frac{\Phi^{\Phi^{\Phi}}}{\Phi}})^{\Phi^{\Phi}} + ({\Phi^{\Phi^{\Phi}}}*{\Phi})^{\Phi} \approx 2008 $$

In other words

> $ \Phi^{15} + \Phi^{13} + \Phi^{10} \approx 1364.00 + 521.00 + 122.99 \approx 2007.99 \approx 2008 $

Now this uses

> 17 $\Phi$ -

we can attempt to reduce this by factoring out

> $\Phi^{9}$,

like so

> $$ (\Phi*{\Phi^{\Phi^{\Phi^{\Phi}}}}) ( ({\Phi*\Phi*\Phi})^\Phi + {\Phi^{\Phi^{\Phi}}} + \Phi ) $$

Which is the same result but only uses my current final score of

> 13

Comment: I literally just posted a comment with the same sentiment. +1

Comment: The "at the loss of accuracy" is akin to saying "if we can use a ceiling function", which was explicitly outlawed, so I don't think this should then go on to say "my current final score of...".

Comment: @JonathanAllan Disagree, because it's referring to the accuracy of the result, not an intermediate step. If I tried to use something like `ceiling(phi)` in the calculation I'd say that is against the rules.

Comment: Huh? When push comes to shove you did not make 2008 using that many phis, you made something close which would require an unavailable operation at the end. You could say "at the expense of acuraccy I can do it in one" (or zero maybe!).

Comment: @JonathanAllan If you want to feel that way, sure. I could add a few more powers of phi and make it even closer but it still wouldn't be exact. I would still argue that this is in the spirit of the competition. And you can't deny the elegance of it - I mean, c'mon, base phi is pretty darned cool. So go pee in someone else's soup...

Answer (score 5):

As an opening bid, I think I can do it using

> $44$  $\Phi$s

which is

> $\left(\Phi.\Phi - \left( \frac{\Phi}{\Phi.\Phi}\right)\right)^\left(\left(\Phi.\Phi - \left( \frac{\Phi}{\Phi.\Phi}\right)\right)^\left( \Phi.\Phi + \left(\frac{\Phi}{\Phi.\Phi.\Phi} \right)\right)+\left( \Phi.\Phi + \left(\frac{\Phi}{\Phi.\Phi.\Phi} \right)\right)\right)$ 
>  $ -\left(\left(\Phi.\Phi - \left( \frac{\Phi}{\Phi.\Phi}\right)\right)^\left( \Phi.\Phi + \left(\frac{\Phi}{\Phi.\Phi.\Phi} \right)\right) * \left[\left(\Phi.\Phi - \left( \frac{\Phi}{\Phi.\Phi}\right)\right)+\left( \Phi.\Phi + \left(\frac{\Phi}{\Phi.\Phi.\Phi} \right)\right)\right]\right) = 2008$

Idea:

> We use the following two equations 
>  $\left(\Phi.\Phi - \left( \frac{\Phi}{\Phi.\Phi}\right)\right) = 2$ 
>  $\left( \Phi.\Phi + \left(\frac{\Phi}{\Phi.\Phi.\Phi} \right)\right) = 3$

together with

> $2^\left(2^3+3\right) - (2^3 * (2+3)) = 2008$

although I think it should be possible with fewer.

Comment: Guessing you used a script for that, but still.. impressive!

Comment: Actually, I didn't need to. Everything I've written here can be derived on pen and paper, in just a few lines, from the equation $\Phi^2  = \Phi + 1$. I'm not even sure this answer is optimal.

Comment: Oh ok thats even more impressive!

Comment: Reduces to 40 by using my version of 2.

Comment: ...or 28 using my newer method.