# Make 439204 from Φ (Golden Ratio)

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

In [my last](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59615/make-2008-from-%CE%A6-golden-ratio) [formation-of-numbers](/questions/tagged/formation-of-numbers) question I somehow tricked myself, because I wanted to make a puzzle about a number that looks like a year. But the complicated solution I thought of turned out to be outperformed by a much simpler ansatz. Here is a puzzle that (hopefully) has my intended solution as optimum:

Make the number $439204$ by using an arbitrary number of [$\Phi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)s and

- the operators $+$, $−$, $\cdot$, $/$ (including unary "$-$")

  exponentiation

  brackets $($ $)$.

The aim is to use as few $\Phi$s as possible.

You may not use operators or functions other than in this list, so don't even ask for rounding ($\lfloor$ $\rfloor$, $\lceil$ $\rceil$) or logarithm ($\log_a (x)$). If you want to use roots, this is ok as long as you express them as exponent: $\sqrt[n]{x} = x^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Comment: Could you clarify whether we are allowed unary minus ?

Comment: Unary minus is allowed. I edited the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can do

> 38 ... no, 18,

as follows.

> Write $L_n$ for the $n$th Lucas number, so $L_0=2$, $L_1=1$, and $L_{n+2}=L_{n+1}+L_n$. It happens that $L_{27}=439204$. And we have $L_n=\phi^n+(-\phi)^{-n}$. And $27=3^3$.

Therefore,

> $$\begin{eqnarray}439204 &=& \phi^{27}+(-\phi)^{-27} \\ &=& \phi^{27}-\phi^{-27} \\ &=& \phi^{\left(\left(\frac{\phi+\phi+\phi}{\phi}\right)^{\left(\frac{\phi+\phi+\phi}{\phi}\right)}\right)} - \phi^{-\left(\left(\frac{\phi+\phi+\phi}{\phi}\right)^{\left(\frac{\phi+\phi+\phi}{\phi}\right)}\right)}. \end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: In that case I think it should be possible in 18

Comment: Ah - you saw it too :)

Comment: Yup, seconds after posting 38.

Comment: I really should've done what I was going to do when I first saw the number change... an oeis search https://oeis.org/search?q=439204&language=english&go=Search

Comment: Yep :-). (What I actually did when I saw the new number was to look up "Lucas numbers". But I already knew about the nice formula for those.)

Answer (score 0):

Using a similar method to my answer to the previous question...

> <s>43</s>  42

Since

> $N = \frac{\phi + \phi + ...}{\phi}$
>  and
>  $439204 = 2^{(2^3)}\cdot 5\cdot 7^3+2\cdot (3^4+1)$
>
>  $\frac{\phi + \phi}{\phi}^{(\frac{\phi + \phi}{\phi}^\frac{\phi + \phi + \phi}{\phi})}\cdot \frac{\phi + \phi + \phi + \phi + \phi}{\phi} \cdot \frac{\phi + \phi + \phi + \phi + \phi + \phi + \phi}{\phi} ^\frac{\phi + \phi + \phi}{\phi}  + \frac{\phi + \phi}{\phi}\cdot (\frac{\phi + \phi + \phi}{\phi} ^\frac{\phi + \phi + \phi + \phi}{\phi} + \frac{\phi}{\phi})$